# how do i find the fourier transform of the function $f_a(x)=e^{a|x|}$

Tags: fourier-analysis

Having trouble finding the fourier transform of the function $f_a(x)=e^{-a|x|}$ , where $a>0$

I currently have that 
$$
\mathcal{F}(f_ax) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-ax}\, e^{ i s x} \,ds= \dfrac{-1}{is-a}\sqrt{\dfrac2{\pi}}
$$

I have missed out the working since it takes me too long to format everything, however this is the answer I got, however I dont believe I'm right, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should show the work you did since it would help users of this site determine where you are encountering difficulties.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed half of the fourier integral. We have$\def\F{\mathcal F}$
\begin{align*}
  \F(f_a)(s) &= \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\bigl(-a|x|\bigr)\exp(-isx)\, dx\\
   &=  \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \int_0^\infty \exp\bigl(-(is+a)x\bigr)\, dx
     + \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \int_{-\infty}^0 \exp\bigl(-(is-a)x\bigr)\, dx\\
   &= \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \frac 1{a + is} + \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \frac 1{a-is}\\
   &= \frac 1{(2\pi)^{1/2}} \frac{2a}{a^2 + s^2}\\
   &= \sqrt{\frac 2\pi} \frac a{a^2 + s^2}
\end{align*}